# My password is not working in System Preferences unlock prompt

Tags: macos, user-account

I keep getting this prompt when I try to install a app or anything:

[image]

Usually I just enter the password and everything is fine (before the username field would be filled). Now it is not accpeting my password. Since I use the same password for iCloud I changed the password and enter the new password but it is still not working.

Comment: Have you tried the user **Shahbaz Younis** at this prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You're not an administrator. In the list of accounts, your account shows as Managed, not Administrator. The credentials asked for in that prompt are that of an administrator, as asked for by ‘Enter an administrator's name and password’, which means you should enter the other user account's credentials. The username field is only autofilled when you are currently logged in as an administrator.

Comment: ive always used this account and for admin privileges aswell.This is the first time im seeing this , and i tried all the passwords on that account but it just wont accept anything.